# How do I query resources in the nested collection in eve-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mongodb, sqlalchemy, eve

I am using **Eve-SQLAlchemy==0.5.0**

I would like to perform a nested query using Postman on my users such that I find all users that are within a specified organization.

Using SQL I would write my query such that:

```
select * from app_user
left join user_organization on user_organization.user_id = app_user.id
left join organization on organization.id = user_organization.organization_id
where organization.id = 2
```

---

I have a user model, an organization model, and a relational model linking the two user_organization.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, func, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class BaseModel(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    __abstract__ = True
    _created = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    _updated = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    _etag = Column(String(40))


class User(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'app_user'
    organizations = relationship("Organization", secondary=UserOrganization.__tablename__)


class Organization(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'organization'
    name = Column(String)


class UserOrganization(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'user_organization'
    user_id = Column(Integer,
                     ForeignKey('app_user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    organization_id = Column(Integer,
                             ForeignKey('organization.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

In my settings.py I have the resources registered:

```
# Resource Registration
DOMAIN = DomainConfig({
    'organization': ResourceConfig(Organization),
    'user': ResourceConfig(User)
}).render()
```

---

I have a series of postman collections setup, and using a GET request I can easily query any attribute... `GET localhost:5000/user?where={"id":1}`

I have tried (amongst many other things):

```
GET user?where={"organizations": {"organization_id" :2 }}
GET user?where={"organizations": 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems it's not possible at the moment due to a bug. I will try to fix it within the next week.

The code in https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/blob/master/eve_sqlalchemy/parser.py#L73 is causing a GET `?where={"organizations": 2}` to result in a SQL expression like `user_id = 42 AND organization_id = 42` is generated. Which rarely makes any sense.

Comment: Really appreciate it!
My current data set is not so large that I could not do a brute for solution, or always have the option to drop into a regular flask endpoint to do the querying.

Comment: @JustinBeall Could you try your application with the [fix-where-relations branch](https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/tree/fix-where-relations)? Your above mentioned query `GET user?where={"organizations": 2}` should work now. If you can confirm this, I will prepare the release of Eve-SQLAlchemy 0.5.1.

Comment: I am sorry I did not respond to this until now.I will try to take a peak here soon.
I ended up working around the code by doing the additional filtering in the code post response.